# script of Comparing 2 columns and copy value if match between two google sheets,

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare

Can Anyone please help to share the google script of compare value between two sheets and return different value on 1st sheet if value match?

For example

Sheet1 (Before)

DESCRIPTION MEMBERCODE 
BOX 1 A
BOX 2 B 
BOX 3 C 
BOX 4 D
BOX 5 E

Sheet2

MEMBERCODE PRICE
E $14
A $10
D $13
C $12
B $11

Sheet1 (After)

DESCRIPTION MEMBERCODE PRICE 
BOX 1 A $10
BOX 2 B $11
BOX 3 C $12 
BOX 4 D $13
BOX 5 E $14

Comment: Can you provide the code or functions you used to try it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function compareAndCombine() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var v1=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var v2=sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow()-1,sh2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var v2A=v2.map(function(r){return r[0]});
  v1.forEach(function(r,i){
    var idx=v2A.indexOf(r[1]);
    if(idx>-1) {
      v1[i].splice(2,0,v2[idx][1]);
    }else{
      v1[i].splice(2,0,'');
    }
  });
  sh1.getRange(2,1,v1.length,v1[0].length).setValues(v1);
}
```

Comment: There is no Sheet3, but only copy 'PRICE' column based on 'MEMBERCODE', I change sh1 to 'Sheet1' and sh2 to 'Sheet2', and run the script, but nothing happened. no error while run the script.

Comment: Please just share a copy of your current script.  I'll fix it.

Comment: The PRICE COLUMN from 'Sheet2' (Sheet2!B2:B6) still not showing on 'Sheet1' (Sheet1!C2:C6) by matching both MEMBERCODE (Sheet1!B2:B6) and (Sheet2!A2:A6), here is the google sheet file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fi5NG4iIAOqT_7Iw6JI9_VGhTt0Z4UTGuxhrYf608Bg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it works good!, this is simple and neat script. thank you very much. Cooper